# \qedhere warning in description in proof

Tags: amsthm, description

When I design my *iff-proof* as follows, I get this warning:

> The \qedhere command may not work correctly here

Is there any way to fix this warning, since the result looks fine, or accomplish this formatting another way? [Edit: I’d like to have the qed-square at the same height as the second "Wohoo."]

[image: Looks fine]

This is a small working example which assures the style above:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setdescription{font=\normalfont\itshape}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}$ $\par
\begin{description}[topsep=0pt]
    \item[\enquote{$\Rightarrow$}] This is one direction of the proof. It might include some formulas. Something along the lines of $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Wohoo.

    \item[\enquote{$\Leftarrow$}] This is the other direction of the proof. It might include some formulas. Something along the lines of $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Wohoo.$\hfill\qedhere$
\end{description}
\end{proof}
Some follow up text. And more of it. And more of it. Let's make it two lines of follow up text for some reason.

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misusing `\qedhere`. It should be simply that, not `$\hfill\qedhere$`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setdescription{font=\normalfont\itshape}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}\mbox{}
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
\item[\enquote{$\Rightarrow$}] This is one direction of the proof.
It might include some formulas. Something along the lines
of $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Wohoo.

\item[\enquote{$\Leftarrow$}] This is the other direction of the proof.
It might include some formulas. Something along the lines of $a^2+b^2=c^2$.
Wohoo.\qedhere
\end{itemize}
\end{proof}

Some follow up text. And more of it. And more of it. Let's make it two
lines of follow up text for some reason.

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, instead of `$ $\par`, just type `\mbox{}`. I used `itemize`, because the italic quotes around the arrows are just awful.

I find it better style to just use plain paragraphs, instead of itemized proofs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\enquote{$\Rightarrow$} This is one direction of the proof.
It might include some formulas. Something along the lines
of $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Wohoo.

\enquote{$\Leftarrow$} This is the other direction of the proof.
It might include some formulas. Something along the lines of $a^2+b^2=c^2$.
Wohoo.
\end{proof}

Some follow up text. And more of it. And more of it. Let's make it two
lines of follow up text for some reason.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just as clear, even better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Just place `\qedhere` after `proof` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setdescription{font=\normalfont\itshape}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}$ $\par
\begin{description}[topsep=0pt]
    \item[\enquote{$\Rightarrow$}] This is one direction of the proof. It might include some formulas. Something along the lines of $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Wohoo.

    \item[\enquote{$\Leftarrow$}] This is the other direction of the proof. It might include some formulas. Something along the lines of $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Wohoo.
\end{description}
\end{proof}
$\hfill\qedhere$
Some follow up text. And more of it. And more of it. Let’s make it two lines of follow up text for some reason.

\end{document}
```

If you do not want to place `\qed` everytime you use the `proof` environment you can redefine it writting in preamble:

```
\let\Oldproof\proof
\renewenvironment{proof}{\begin{Oldproof}}{\end{Oldproof}$\hfill\qed$}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also be sure to use `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$`. I have found a case where, even though the `amsthm` package is loaded correctly after `amsmath`, there still was a warning about `\qedhere` possibly not working (it looked fine), and changing the display math command removed it, for reasons`unknown to me.